# How to add an attribute that contains a hyphen to a WTForms field

Tags: python, wtforms

Calling a WTForms field object produces the rendered field, and any arguments are taken as attributes, for instance.

```
form.field(attribute='value')
```

would return something like

```
<input attribute='value'>
```

How can I add HTML5 custom data attributes such as data-provide which contain hyphens, making them unparseable in python as a single keyword argument?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a dictionary with the corresponding key-value pairs and use ** to pass it to the field call:

```
attrs = {'data-provide': "foo"}
form.field(**attrs)
```

*Edit*: Looks like the comment by @NiklasB should be part of the answer:
For those using [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with [flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), use: `{{ form.field( **{'data-provide': 'foo'} ) }}` in your template.

Comment: For those using flask with flask-WTF, use: {{ form.field( **{'data-provide': 'foo'} ) }} in your template

Comment: Thanks for this -- awesome work. I did the following: {{ form.phone( **{'data-format': '(ddd) ddd-dddd', 'class':'form-control bfh-phone', 'placeholder':'Phone'} ) }}

Comment: Its works, but why is this working only when we create and unpack the dictionary and not working when we directly provide the parameters?

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessary to use a dictionary like that in the form.field function call. The ** unpacks the dictionary items into named parameters for the function, so just add the parameters instead:

{{ form.field( data-provide='foo') }}

But do so AFTER any required parameters for that field.
In other words, why unpack a dictionary right there when you can just add the parameters?

Comment: This doesn't work because the wtforms parameters are Python syntax, and a property with a hyphen is not valid Python syntax. Doing this raises a TemplateSyntaxError.