# Flask- WTF with knockout.js , JavaScript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, flask-wtforms

I need to use Knockout.js , JavaScript and Ajax with Flask-WTF (forms), So here is some sample code

```
<form action="{{ url_for('post_it') }}" class="navbar-form form-inline" method="post" id="new_postform">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <fieldset>
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

{% from "macro/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

            <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
                        {{ render_field(form.poster, class="form-control", size="5", placeholder="Post Anything" ) }}

                    </div>
            </div>
```

Now I am writing a JavaScript snipped at the bottom of the page as

```
{% block tail_script %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/jquery.validate.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/additional-methods.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#new_postform').validate({
    rules: {
        form.poster: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Now Here I take form id named "new_postform" but in Knockoutjs I need to write the inline code under  data-bind="text: name" kind of snippet that I need to write in

```
{{ render_field(form.poster,data-bind="text: name", class="form-control", size="5", placeholder="Post Anything" ) }}
```

But this gives me template error does Flask-WTF does not support data-bind inline. Do I need to write some advanced macros to accomplish the MVVM support of Knockoutjs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an attribute that contains a hyphen to a WTForms field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284732/how-to-add-an-attribute-that-contains-a-hyphen-to-a-wtforms-field)

Comment: well thanks nemev for refering me to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the data-bind as follows in this example of an email field:

{{ form.email(required=true, **{'data-bind':'value: email'}) }}

Reference: [Snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/107/)